# Loading Screen with Minimum Display Time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a fixed div with a solid background and some text that I am using as a loading screen that fades out when the the page is fully loaded via $(window).load . The catch is since there is actual information on the loader, it needs to be up for a minimum amount of time before fading out. However, in the event that the page loads faster than that minimum time, I do not want it to disappear early, and I also don't want it to stay up past the minimum time once the site is loaded as well, and this is where I am stumped.

Logically it needs to operate like this:
-fade in, wait 5 seconds
-page loads
-if 5 seconds has passed, fade out immediately
-else wait out the remaining time ONLY, then fade out (in other words, don't start counting 5 seconds after onload)

I usually just have an easier loader that displays immediately and then I addClass to hide it via CSS transitions on opacity after onload, but since I need to fade the loading text in and then out and also maintain a minimum time without just adding it as a delay after onload, this is a bit trickier.

This was asked here a few years ago but without a proper answer: [jQuery loading screen with minimum viewing time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20123991/jquery-loading-screen-with-minimum-viewing-time)

Would prefer to stick with JS/jQuery & CSS. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just set a `timeout` for five seconds, check if window is loaded, if so, hide it.

On load, check if five seconds has elapsed, and if so, hide it.

I would do it like this:

```
var loader = (function(window, $loadingScreen) {

    var elapsed = false;
    var loaded = false;

    setTimeout(function() {
        elapsed = true;
        if (loaded)
            hideLoadingScreen();
    }, 5000);

    var hideLoadingScreen = function() {
        //do whatever
    }

    $(window).on('load', function() {
        if (elapsed) {
            hideLoadingScreen();
        }
    });
}(window, $('#loader'))
```

So - to simplify, we care only about whether both the page has loaded, and five seconds has passed.  So, if at both of those events, we check whether the other has already happened, we know that it will trigger either at five seconds (if the page has loaded), or when the page has loaded (if five seconds has passed).

Comment: This is perfect, thanks so much dave, really appreciate the explanation as well!

Comment: Quick question: what does `(window, $('#loader'))` do?

Thanks so much.

Comment: @rbross3030 - I used an IIFE (immediately invoked function expression), so  it is just passing window and $('#loader') to the `function(window, $loadingScreen)` arguments - `window` remains `window`, `$('#loader')` becomes `$loadingScreen`.  It kind of enumerates the dependencies on the outside scope, and prevents the inside scope from leaking.

Answer (score 0):

https://jsfiddle.net/4k7uxdxz/

Use CSS to take care of the animating. This will ensure that the animation will take effect as soon as the page opens and will take 5s to fade in.

```
.opener {
  opacity: 0;
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  animation: fadeIn 5s forwards;
}

@keyframes fadeOut {
  from {
    opacity: 1;
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeIn {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
```

When the DOM is ready simply change the animation to fade out

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $(".opener").on("animationend", () => {
    $(".opener").css("animation", "fadeOut 5s forwards")
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks but this isn't what I am looking for. I don't just want a 5 second animation, please see dave's answer below.